# Chrome - режим headless - настройки

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Использую в проекте, Chrome в режиме headless, знаю только одну надстройку `--window-size=1920x1080`

Какие существуют ещё ?

На данный момент ищу способ отключить картинки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе доступны все аргументы, что и Chromium [command line arguments](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).
Может найдете нужный.